# ニュースアプリのランキング機能

Tags: swift

iOSでニュースアプリ制作しております。

多くのニュースアプリで(おそらくアクセス数だと思われる)ランキングが24時間、一週間、一ヶ月とあります。

このようなシステムの実装方法はどのようになっているのでしょうか？

Comment: RSSでニュース記事を取得する事まではできました。アプリ側で記事のアクセス数を集計して、その集計を基にランキング化しているのでしょうか？

Comment: どちらかというとアプリではなくサーバ側での話になる気がします。

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。少しずつ仕組みが分かってきました。

Comment: 記事を自ら作成しないキュレーションアプリであれば、記事の並べ方が最も重要であり、そこを尋ねるのはいかがなものかと思います。また並べ方は企業秘密であったり、特許で保護されていたりするかもしれません。そのような内容を回答すると回答者にもリスクが伴うため、答えが集まりづらい質問に思います。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/117447

Answer (score 2):

ランキングの指標としては「記事が表示された回数」「記事をクリックして元サイトを開いた回数」などが考えられます。
仮に後者の「クリックされた回数」とするなら、一緒に「クリックされた日時」も記録しておけば、特定の期間ごとのランキングを集計・生成するのはそれほど難しい話ではないかと思います。

コメント欄でも言及しましたが、アプリ内の閉じた環境で回数を記録してもそれはアプリ利用者個人に特化したデータになってしまうので、実際にはサーバも用意してデータを集計・配信する形になるのではないでしょうか。